# put in multiply or divide in input field to perform either multiply or divide on the other 2 input fields

Tags: javascript

Hey guys im trying to create a function that takes 3 arguments. The first argument is supposed to be "MULTIPLY" or "DIVIDE" in an input field, then followed by two numbers which are also in separate input fields, that should be either multipled or divided according based on the first argument. I cant figure out exactly how i'm supposed to write this down in code.

this is my code so far;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="ovning3-3.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1></h1>
<p>

</p>


<input id="first" type="text">
<input id="second" type="text">
<input id="third" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Multiply" onclick="multiply()">
<input type="button" value="Divide" onclick="divide()">
<input type="button" value="Multiply and Divide" onclick="multiplyAndDivide()">

</body>
</html>
```

and the java script;

```
function multiply() {

    var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("third").value;
    var result = (x * y) * z

    alert(result)

}

function divide() {

    var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("third").value;
    var result = (x / y) / z

    alert(result)

}


function multiplyAndDivide() {

    multiply();
    divide();

}
```

Any help out there?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @NaimRajib haha sorry if I missed out on typing the question. well the question is how do you write the javascript code for putting multiply in the input field and to make it multiply the numbers in the other two input fields.

Comment: I am not clear about your requirements? do you want to put the result any of these input fields?

Comment: no. as you can see the result gets alerted after. but what im looking for is a way to write in the input field "multiply" and it will multiply whats in the other two input fields. right now im getting NaN(not a number). @NaimRajib

Comment: See my answer. GO jsfiddle to demonstart this. Also don't forget to upvote and also accept this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is what you want

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function calculate() {
        var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
        var d = document.getElementById("decision").value;
        if (d=="*")
           result = x*y;
        else if(d=="/")
           result = x/y;
        alert(result)}
</script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1></h1>
<select id="decision">
    <option value="*">Multiply</option>
    <option value="/">Divide</option>
</select><br>
<input id="first" type="text">
<input id="second" type="text"><br>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()">
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you need any further explaination

Comment: thank you @msngupta! I understand the code as well. would this work as well if it were an input field instead of a select id? ergo <input id="decision" type="text">.

Comment: Yes, it will but for multiply you have to provide "*" and for divide you have to provide "/" in the decision input(without quotes). Instead if you want to provide somthing like "multiply" and "divide" in the input then change the comparison condition of "d" to `d=="multiply"` and `d=="divide"` to make it work. I hope this helped

Comment: ahh I just tried it out with an input field and it worked. I had to change "if d=="x"" to "if d=="multiply"" and the samething with the others in the if and else if. thank you alot!

Comment: this can be very flexible as well right? I mean I could easy put in an add and subtract function as well in the if and else as well right?

Comment: Okay I tried it but the add and subtraction operations wont work. even though its the same. I tried replacing them over all and adding parseInt before the document but still same thing.

okay I upped yours, I will go through the rest of them as well. Thank you a lot msngupta

Comment: I need 15 reputation to upvote apparently but I green marked it :P

I actually can't figure out. I tried replacing add with multiply and etc and putting x+y but the javascript wasn't alerting the result?

function calculate() {
        var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("first").value);
        var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("second").value);
        var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("decision").value);
        if (z=="add")
           result = x+y;
        else if(z=="subtract")
           result = x-y;
  

        alert(result)

Comment: still didnt work though. could it be the if and else if thats wrong? green marked your answer :)

** edit

nvm got it to work. one misspell that I missed >_<

Thank you a lot msngupta. I understood a lot from your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one function

```
function multiplyOrDivide(todo){
var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
var z = document.getElementById("third").value;
if(todo==0){
    alert(Number(x*y*z));
}
else{
    if(y!=0 || z!=0){
        alert(Number(x/y)/z);
    }
 }
```

}

In onclick you can pass options as multiplyOrDivide(1)

Comment: How you will pass todo parameter value? I mean if i want to flexibility of choice?

Comment: Use onclick="multiplyOrDivide(0)" in your html for multiplication and onclick="multiplyOrDivide(1)" in your html for division.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select menu to choice which operation you want to perform. To use js functionality, you can take a look this:

```
function calculate() {
  var selected_operation = document.getElementById("operation");
  var operation = selected_operation.options[selected_operation.selectedIndex].value;

  if (operation == 'multiply') 
     multiply(operation);
  else if (operation == 'divide') 
     divide();
  else if (operation == 'mulitiply_division')
     multiplyAndDivide();
}

function multiply() {
  var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
  var z = document.getElementById("third").value;
  var result = (x * y) * z

  alert(result);
}

function divide() {
  var x = document.getElementById("first").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("second").value;
  var z = document.getElementById("third").value;
  var result = (x / y) / z

  alert(result);
}

function multiplyAndDivide() {
  multiply();
  divide();
}
```

To see the whole scenario, please visit **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w14xmqr6/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mul()
{
 var a = document.getElementById("v1").value;
 var b = document.getElementById("v2").value;
 
 document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Multiplication is: " + a * b;
}
function div()
{
 var a = document.getElementById("v1").value;
 var b = document.getElementById("v2").value;
 
 document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Division is: " + a / b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
body{
padding-left: 80px;
}
</style>


<body>

<p id="ans"></p>

<input type="text" placeholder="Value 1" id="v1"><br><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Value 2" id="v2"><br><br>

<input type="button" onclick="mul()" id="mul" value="Multiplication">
<input type="button" id="div" onclick="div()" value="Division">

</body>
</html>
```

Explanation:
document.getElementById(id).value: The value property sets or returns the value of the value attribute of a text field.

document.getElementById("result").innerHTM : The innerHTML property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element.

Comment: Need some explanation also!

Comment: @IrfanShaikh Edit your question and add the explanation there instead of using comments.